# How to convert a Java object to String using Saxon

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxon, xalan

I am facing a problem with Xalon while converting Java object to String, i.e empty open close tags are converted to self closing tags. eg. `<span></span>` gets converted to `</span>`.

I have fixed simliar problem while using Saxon XSL transformer. Is it possible to use Saxon to convert a java `Object` to `String` instead of Xalon.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm sure you mean `<span/>` for the self-closing tag.

Second: why is this a problem? If you are generating XML, `<span></span>` means exactly the same as `<span/>`, and will be treated the same by any XML parser. (If you're reading the XML without an XML parser, then DON'T). On the other hand, if you are generating HTML, then specifying method="html" should be all you need to do, whether you are using Xalan or Saxon.

Third: I can't see any relationship between your serialization problem and the task of converting Java objects to strings.

You can certainly do such things in Saxon. The documentation for calling Java methods from Saxon can be found here: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/intro.xml (Sorry there's so much of it, but I don't know enough about your situation to give you a more precise pointer).